postgres backup start stop from psql and linux cli
I want to perform below steps

Put DB in backup mode
Take snapshot of volume
Stop backup mode

But when I try as below, at #3 I get "Did you call pg_backup_start()?" error.
Looks like start and stop both need to be called from same psql prompt?
bash-4.4$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U $PGUSER -c "select pg_backup_start ('bkp-001'); select pg_sleep(30)" &
[1] 47018
bash-4.4$ psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U $PGUSER -c "select pg_backup_stop()"
ERROR:  backup is not in progress
HINT:  Did you call pg_backup_start()?

Is there any other way to achieve this?

yes, pg_backup_stop should be called from the same database connection as pg_backup_start. Moreover, you should take care of pg_backup_stop return values correctly. What's why it is called "the Low Level API" in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP

It depends on what version you are using.

It was renamed pg_backup_start in v15.  But yeah, if that is the name then the "exclusive backup" option no longer exists and he needs to adapt to the times.

You need to run pg_backup_start() and pg_backup_stop() in the same psql session, you you have to keep that session open while you are backing up the data directory. Furthermore, you have to get the data from the label_file result column of pg_backup_stop(), write it to a file called backup_label and add it to the backup.
This is because the exclusive backup API has been removed in PostgreSQL v15.
See this article for details. You could try my scripts to make the transition easier.

An alternative:
#!/bin/bash

# Configurações
PG_USER="postgres"
PG_HOST="localhost"
PG_PORT="5432"
BACKUP_DIR="/caminho/para/diretorio/backup"
DATA_DIR="/var/lib/postgresql/16/main"
BACKUP_LABEL="meu_backup_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
LABEL_FILE="$BACKUP_DIR/backup_label"

# Cria o diretório de backup se não existir
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR"

# Inicia o processo de backup no PostgreSQL
echo "Iniciando o backup no PostgreSQL..."

# Abre uma sessão psql e executa os comandos dentro do mesmo bloco EOF
psql -U $PG_USER -h $PG_HOST -p $PG_PORT <<EOF
BEGIN;

*-- Inicia o backup*
SELECT pg_backup_start('$BACKUP_LABEL');

*-- Neste ponto, o backup está em andamento e os arquivos podem ser copiados*
\\! tar -cvzf "$BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_LABEL.tar.gz" --exclude="$DATA_DIR/pg_wal" -C "$DATA_DIR" .

*-- Finaliza o backup e obtém o label do backup*
\o $LABEL_FILE
SELECT * FROM pg_backup_stop();
\o

COMMIT;
EOF

# Verifica se o comando anterior foi bem-sucedido
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Erro: Falha ao executar o backup PITR."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Backup PITR concluído com sucesso."
echo "Backup salvo em $BACKUP_DIR/$BACKUP_LABEL.tar.gz."
echo "Arquivo de label salvo em $LABEL_FILE."

